# ElasticSearch Aggregations - sum_other_doc_count in a (Term?) Query?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

By default, a Terms aggregation gives me the top-10 most-popular terms, and their counts, and then a sum_other_doc_count field representing the "Other" items.

I can display these to the user:

```
first (150)
second (122)
third(111)
...
other(19)
```

...The user can then filter their results by choosing one of the terms.  I apply a TermFilter using the term they select.  Works fine.

...However.......Is there a way I can create a filter which represents "other" (ie all terms except the top-10) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so. You can hack together something related (but not quite the same) with [terms](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html) and [not](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-not-filter.html) filters, though, which returns all documents in which the top terms do NOT appear. I'm going to use top 5 for simplicity.

So I created an index and added some random Latin text:

```
PUT /test_index
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "number_of_replicas": 0
    }
}

POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec rhoncus dictum ligula, quis volutpat diam fringilla ut."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"text": "Nulla ac gravida ipsum. Pellentesque placerat mattis pharetra. Praesent sapien lorem, auctor in imperdiet vel, lacinia vel diam."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"text": "Mauris a risus ut eros posuere rutrum. Nunc scelerisque diam ex, consequat mollis sem facilisis in."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"text": "Maecenas lacinia sollicitudin ultricies. Aenean id eleifend sapien. In et justo accumsan, cursus mi vel, consectetur augue. Nullam in quam ac magna iaculis finibus quis ut risus."}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc"}}
{"text": "Donec dolor eros, rhoncus ultricies quam et, dapibus egestas libero."}
```

then got the top 5 terms:

```
POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
    "aggs": {
        "top_terms":{
            "terms":{
                "field": "text",
                "size": 5
            }
        }
    }
}
...
{
   "took": 4,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 5,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "top_terms": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "diam",
               "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
               "key": "in",
               "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
               "key": "ut",
               "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
               "key": "ac",
               "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
               "key": "consectetur",
               "doc_count": 2
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

then I can construct a filter that gives me back the docs in which the top 5 terms do NOT appear, like:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "constant_score": {
         "filter": {
            "not": {
               "filter": {
                  "terms": {
                     "text": [
                        "diam",
                        "in",
                        "ut",
                        "ac",
                        "consectetur"
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "boost": 1.2
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "4uoLr70rRXulHHc7N3Ujmw",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "text": "Donec dolor eros, rhoncus ultricies quam et, dapibus egestas libero."
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I know this doesn't really answer your question, but maybe it will give you some ideas.

Here is the code I used (if you're using ES 1.4 you'll have to turn on CORS to be able to use the code in the browser):

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/93b69375c5491f1b0458e2053a08e65006f34a1c